# JSLint Error: Unexpected 'this'

Tags: javascript, constructor, jslint

Having trouble understanding why JSLint is surprised by my use of `this` in the following code:

```js
function testConstr (x) {
    'use strict';
    this.joker = "Whyyy sooo seriousss?";
    this.x = x;
}
```

For both property assignments, JSLint says: *Unexpected 'this'.* How do I correct my code?

Comment: Your `this` is not necessarily bad. Is `testConstr` used as a constructor? Do you call it with `call` or `apply`?

Comment: If you find JSLint to have too many arbitrary warnings, you way want to look into JSHint.

Comment: What happens if you capitalize it to `TestConstr`? Does the warning remain?

Comment: @apsillers Yep, that was my first move too. Still busted. The new JSLint wants to encourage you to stop using `this` altogether. I mean, admittedly, scope really is one of the most confusing topics for new (and old!) JavaScript coders, though I don't know that that's enough reason to ban its use by default. His [rationale](http://jslint.com/help.html) is "Having `this` in the language makes it harder to talk about the language". That's not *wrong*, I guess. Probably worth trying for a while.

Comment: JSLint now offers an option to suppress this complaint. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30603515/1497596).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your code *might* be perfectly correct (it might also be problematic, depending on how you call `testConstr`).

My suggestion is: tell JSLint to shut up

[image]

Or don't use JSLint at all.

Comment: I would call it using the `new` keyword (i.e. use it as an object constructor). Sorry if that wasn't clear. So in other words, JSLint doesn't automatically expect me to use a constructor pattern? Not helpful for nubes like me . . .

Comment: @jdw If you use `new` it should be perfectly fine. JSLint is more than paranoid.

Comment: Yeah, that is also one option but what if I don't want to suppress this warning by using this JSLint directive.

Answer (score 32):

> [So in other words, JSLint doesn't automatically expect me to use a constructor pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314944/jslint-error-unexpected-this#comment48725505_30315031)

You know, I think you're right. Your question bugged me, and I signed up for [Crockford's JSLint discussion group](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736) and [asked](https://plus.google.com/112458378606572101777/posts/QQ9WN6kzPpo). He replied, but ignored the solution I'm going to present, below, which I *think* means that it's okay, the same way JSLint doesn't complain if something passes muster.

<sub>(I'm still waiting for an updated *[Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)*, though.)</sub>

That caveat aside, here's what I'd suggest doing for OO JavaScript that passes Beta JSLint (as of today, anyhow).

I'm going to rewrite an example from MDN's page, "[Introduction to Object Oriented Programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_methods)," which itself uses `this` liberally.

#### With `this`

Here's the original, *unlinted* MDN example from the section linked, above:

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");
var person2 = new Person("Bob");

// call the Person sayHello method.
person1.sayHello(); // logs "Hello, I'm Alice"
person2.sayHello(); // logs "Hello, I'm Bob"
```

That follows the conventions we know and love.

#### Without `this`

It's pretty easy to figure out how to make "constructors" that don't follow that pattern, but we lose use of `prototype`, if I'm not missing something, and have to include all of the object's methods in our constructor that we want *all* of our `Peep`s to share.

```
/*jslint white:true, devel:true */
var Peep = function(firstName) {
    "use strict";
    var peep = {};
    peep.firstName = firstName;

    peep.innerSayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello, I'm " + peep.firstName + ".");
    };

    return peep;
};

var peep1 = new Peep("Bob");
var peep2 = new Peep("Doug");

peep1.innerSayHello();
peep2.innerSayHello();
```

So there's a lintable alternative. That does, other than the `return peep;` and the inner definition of methods, make JavaScript act like many OO-first languages you might encounter. It's not *wrong*, at least.

Not having access to `prototype` isn't horrible; it's really bad news to change `prototype` somewhere that's not right beside the constructor, as your code would go to spaghetti. "*Some `Person`s have `sayGoodbye()` and some don't, depending on if we'd amended the prototype at the point of their construction.*" That's awful. So this alternative convention has its advantages.

You can still, of course, add functions to a single instantiation of `Peep` later, but I'm not sure how you'd access `firstName` without using `this`, so perhaps he wants us to stop munging objects after construction.

```
person1.sayGoodbye = function (other) { 
    console.log("Goodbye, " + other + "."); 
};
```

(I mean, we could also still monkey-patch `Peep` to change it mid-process, but that's horrible, stupid programming. *Usually.*)

#### Inheritance (without `this`)

And inheritance is easy enough, I think.

```
var PeepWithGoodbye = function (firstName) {
    "use strict";
    var peepWithGoodbye = new Peep(firstName);

    peepWithGoodbye.innerSayGoodbye = function (otherPeep) {
        if (undefined === otherPeep) {
            otherPeep = { firstName: "you" };
        }
        console.log("This is " + firstName 
            + " saying goodbye to " + otherPeep.firstName + ".");
    };

    return peepWithGoodbye;
};

var pwg1 = new PeepWithGoodbye("Fred");
pwg1.innerSayHello();           // Hello, I'm Fred.
pwg1.innerSayGoodbye(peep1);    // This is Fred saying goodbye to Bob.
pwg1.innerSayGoodbye();         // This is Fred saying goodbye to you.
```

**EDIT:** See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31898425/1028230) where the asker later found Crockford's suggested means of creating OO javascript. I'm trying to convince that guy to delete that Q&A and move the A here. If he doesn't, I'll probably add his stuff and community wiki it here.

---

**EDIT:** See [this from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) for why it works:

> (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do
> so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

Answer (score 4):

```
'use strict';

var SudoConstructor = (function () {

    /* We need bind, < IE9 needs a (tiny) polyfill */

    function protoEsqDeclare(sudoThis) {
        return sudoThis;
    }

    function protoEsqSet(sudoThis, newValA, newValB) {
        sudoThis.valA = newValA;
        sudoThis.valB = newValB;
    }

    function instanceCreator(valA, valB) {
        var sudoThis = {
            valA: valA,
            valB: valB
        };

        return {
            declare: protoEsqDeclare.bind(null, sudoThis),
            set: protoEsqSet.bind(null, sudoThis)
        };

    }

    return instanceCreator;

}());
```

Answer (score 3):

In a strict mode `this` reference is set to `undefined`.

So both your statements will cause reading properties of the `undefined` object, which will lead to an exception.

> How do I correct my code?

Remove both those lines.

UPD: what I state above is how JSLint treats your code, not how I do that.

Comment: Or: because in non-strict mode such a `this` refers to `window` a `window.joker` and `window.x` is also possible… unless the `this` refers to an event target or something…

Comment: You assume `testConstr` is called as `testConstr()`. Given its name, it may not be the case.

Comment: @Oriol I don't assume anything - it's JSLint that does. I personally find JSLint more destructive than useful.

Comment: Re: destructive: It's worth pointing out the `this` option is new to JSLint beta, which is just a few weeks old. I'm a bit disappointed too. I mean, [Crockford's comment](http://jslint.com/help.html) that, "*[Using `this`] is like pair programming with Abbott and Costello*" isn't real helpful for pointing out what *is* best practice in *exactly* this situation. I'm giving the beta the benefit of the doubt for now, but **note that the original code, as written, lints in [old.jslint.com](http://old.jslint.com/) with just the "messy white space" directive set to true.** So less evil last month.

Answer (score 3):

> JSLint says: Unexpected 'this'. How do I correct my code?

There is no need to correct your code.

In the [help page for JSLint](http://jslint.com/help.html), in the section for the **`/*jslint*/`** directive, a "**Tolerate `this`**" option has been added to the table of available options:

```
+---------------+------+---------------------------------+
| Tolerate this | this | true if this should be allowed. |
+---------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

So, to suppress complaints about the use of `this`, place the following directive into your source file before the first statement:

```js
/*jslint
    this
*/
```

(Note that other **`/*jslint*/`** options may follow `this` by inserting a comma between options. See the JSLint help page.)

Also see [the answer by @Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30315031/1497596) to enable the **"Tolerate `this`"** option in the user interface for JSLint.

Answer (score 1):

An old question I know, but in case it helps anyone, I was watching a [talk](https://vimeo.com/97419177) by Douglas Crockford in which he says (at about 23mins) that he took it out because an attacker could run a method as a function and get access to the global scope with the 'this' keyword.

He says it also meant not using Object.create anymore either - a feature he helped introduce to the language!