# What is the alternative to using a for loop for objects ( not arrays ) and why?

Tags: javascript, jslint

This is not a dup of [JSlint: unexpected 'for'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518554/jslint-unexpected-for)
, please do not mark it as such:

There is no native for loop for looping through an object or object literal ( I know there is a `.forEach` for arrays ).

Why does jslint suggest not using for loops?  How do you loop through an object that does not have `Array.forEach()` or `Array.some()` or similar?

But the bigger more important question, is why is this suggestion made?

Obviously I could use `Object.keys()` and then `forEach()` but this seems like a longer way to do it.

**Originating Code**

```
// on a truthy match returns true and breaks from loop
Pub.someKey = function (obj, func, con) {
    var key;
    if (!Pub.isFunction(func)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (func.call(con, obj[key], key, obj)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
Pub.forSomeKey = Pub.someKey;
```

Comment: *why is this suggestion made?* Because `for...in` will iterate through properties all the way up the prototype chain (that's why you include the `obj.hasOwnProperty` part). Crockford has a lot of very informative things to say about Javascript, but his word is not law. You can turn that particular warning off in jslint I believe.

Comment: Just tell that JSlint thingie to shut up and use a `for` loop.

Comment: @MattBurland is right; you might also see http://jshint.com/docs/options/#forin

Comment: It's worth mentioning that ES6 gives you the ability to define custom iteratable objects - [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: @Shaffanhoon Only iterable objects. Of course, you can define `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() { for(let key of Object.keys(this)) yield [key, this[key]]; };` to make (almost) all objects iterable.

Comment: @MattBurland That's there in JS*H*int, I believe, but no dice in JS*L*int. You can set the `for` directive, but you'll still get `Expected 'Object.keys' and instead saw 'for in'` in this case. [See answer, below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37190218/1028230).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Not really. That's simply a question about how to loop. **It's not a dupe, as that question doesn't care about linting** (no linting tags). Note: The nearly 2k vote answer there does not lint in JSLint (though [this answer's construction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5737136/1028230) does).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer you are looking for is linked in the accepted answer to the question you linked: http://www.jslint.com/help.html#forin

> does not recommend use of the for in statement. Use Object.keys instead.

It goes on to explain why that is recommended.

> The for in statement allows for looping through the names of all of
>   the properties of an object. Unfortunately, it also loops through all
>   of the properties that were inherited through the prototype chain.
>   This has the bad side effect of serving up method functions when the
>   interest is in data properties. If a program is written without
>   awareness of this situation, then it can fail.
>
> The body of every for in statement should be wrapped in an if
>   statement that does filtering. It can select for a particular type or
>   range of values, or it can exclude functions, or it can exclude
>   properties from the prototype. For example,
>
> ```
> for (name in object) {
>     if (object.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
>         ....
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the above code will fail if the object contains a data
>   property named hasOwnProperty. Use Object.keys instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "but this seems like a longer way to do it." Since you get to remove the `hasOwnProperty` check, it's actually, in some ways, much cleaner.

Here's an edited version [that lints](http://jslint.com):

```
/*jslint browser */
/*global Pub */

// on a truthy match returns true and breaks from loop
Pub.someKey = function (obj, func, con) {
    "use strict";
    if (Pub.isFunction(func)) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            if (func.call(con, obj[key], key, obj)) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};
Pub.forSomeKey = Pub.someKey;
```

<sub>(I have a mild dislike of multiple return values, but edited this to use them to more closely match your original. And it gets rid of the "no breaks in `forEach`" issue I mentioned in the original.)</sub>

---

For more on why JSLint doesn't like `for`, see [this Crockford video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo36MrBfTk4&t=21m33s) Setzer22 linked (in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31898425/1028230)). It's interesting watching, and gives a little more context on why he doesn't like `for... in` specifically:

> I've never liked `for... in` because it does that stupid thing where it dredges through the prototype and you get all the methods and stuff that you didn't want. So now we've got `Object.keys`, which returns an array of stuff and you don't get the dredge, and then pass that to `forEach` and its brothers, and it works great. So I don't use `for... in` any more either.

Bonus tip: Watching Crockford at .5 speed while transcribing is *hilarious*, at least for a few minutes.

---

Aside: Unfortunately, [@Oriol's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148560/what-is-the-alternative-to-using-a-for-loop-for-objects-not-arrays-and-why#comment61835136_37148560) and [Matt Burland's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148560/what-is-the-alternative-to-using-a-for-loop-for-objects-not-arrays-and-why/37190218#comment61835134_37148560) comments don't hold, as I imagine @YeWhoseNameCantBeAtted found out. You can add the `for` directive to use standard `for (i=0;...)`, but you'll still get `Expected 'Object.keys' and instead saw 'for in'` in this use case.