# Can be exclude `this` keyword in vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Actually I am following `Douglas Crockford` jslint .

It give warning when i use this.

[jslint] Unexpected 'this'. (unexpected_a)

I can not see any solution around for the error . Don't say add `this` in jslist.options and mark it true.

Is there is any approach without using this?

**EDIT** 
ADDED CODE

// some vue component here

```
   <script>
    export default {
      name: "RefereshPage",
      data() {
        return {
          progressValue: 0
        }
      },
      methods:{
        getRefreshQueue(loader){
          console.log(this.progressValue); // ERROR come here [jslint] Unexpected 'this'. (unexpected_a) 
      }
    }
   }
    </script>
```

Check out this jsfiddle. How can you avoid using this?

https://jsfiddle.net/himmsharma99/ctj4sm7f/5/

Comment: this does not make sense. what does the code look like that you are linting?

Comment: Check out the fiddle.

Comment: Your code seems correct, you may should consider fixing jsLint or try with esLint, ([from here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-get-rid-of-this-key-word-in-vue-app-to-make-it-jslint/41329)).

Comment: I know it is correct . But i am asking is this possible to not use `this` in vue.js . I want to follow jslint without 'this' keyword in javascript . Is this possible , In jsfiddle i have use the code . Is that can be done without `this` ?

Comment: no, this is how vue works

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891931/why-does-jslint-forbid-the-this-keyword

Comment: Linters are there to help you flag potential issues, but they are not inerrant. If a rule is not useful in your particular application, you should disable it, especially for a particularly opinionated one like jsLint.

Answer (score 6):

as i already stated in the comments:

using `this` is an integral part of how vue.js works within a component. you can read more about how it proxies and keeps track of dependencies here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you're better off just disabling your linter or switching to ESLint. But if you insist on a workaround, you could use a mixin and the `$mount` method on a vue instance to avoid using `this` altogether ..

```
    let vm;

    const weaselMixin = {
        methods: {
            getdata() {
                console.log(vm.users.foo.name);
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            vm.getdata();
        }
    };

    vm = new Vue({
        mixins: [weaselMixin],
        data: {
            users: {
                foo: {
                    name: "aa"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    vm.$mount('#app');
```

[See the modified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2uvbc9n/9)

As you can see, this only complicates what should be a fairly simple component. It only goes to show that you shouldn't break the way vue works just to satisfy your linter.

I would suggest you go through [this article](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/working-with-methods-in-vue-js). Particularly important is this part ..

> Vue.js proxies our data and methods to be available in the **this** context. So by writing `this.firstName`, we can access the `firstName` property within the data object. Note that **this** is required.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you appear to be missing a `}` after getRefreshQueue definition. It's not the error your linter is describing, but maybe it got confused by the syntax error?

Comment: added } in question

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the new [Composition API](https://composition-api.vuejs.org). Vue 3 will have in-built support, but you can use [this package](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) for Vue 2 support.

An example of a component without `this` (from vuejs.org):

```
<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    Count is: {{ state.count }}, double is: {{ state.double }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      count: 0,
      double: computed(() => state.count * 2)
    })

    function increment() {
      state.count++
    }

    return {
      state,
      increment
    }
  }
}
</script>
```