# What is the proper way to call another function from a function within the same object that will pass jslint?

Tags: javascript, scope, jslint, function-call, object-literal

What is the proper way to call another function from a function within the same object that will pass jslint?

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Simple example for illustration purposes:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myObject = {
        functionOne: function () {
            console.log("functionOne called by functionTwo");
        },
        functionTwo: function () {
            // jslint Error: 'myObject' is out of scope. (out_of_scope_a);
            // What is the proper way to call another function inside the same Object that will pass jslint?
            myObject.functionOne();

            // jslint Error: Unexpected 'this'. (unexpected_a);
            // What is the proper way to call another function inside the same Object that will pass jslint?
            this.functionOne();
        }
    };

    myObject.functionTwo();
}());
```

Comment: The only error I see from your code is `Unexpected 'this'.`. The `myObject.functionOne();` does not result in the error you describe

Comment: Some good advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314944/jslint-error-unexpected-this). I'd pay particularly close attention to _"tell JSLint to shut up... Or don't use JSLint at all"_

Comment: Yeah, I'd highly recommend using something more configurable, less opinionated, and more modern, like ESLint.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @CertainPerformance you put me on the right track. I had an outdated jslint version. The latest version doesn't mind myObject.functionOne();

Answer (score 0):

adding directives `/*jslint devel, this*/` should fix it. the full list of options/diretives is available @ https://www.jslint.com/

```js
/*jslint devel, this*/
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myObject = {
        functionOne: function () {
            console.log("functionOne called by functionTwo");
        },
        functionTwo: function () {
            // jslint Error: 'myObject' is out of scope. (out_of_scope_a);
            // What is the proper way to call another function inside the
            // same Object that will pass jslint?
            myObject.functionOne();

            // jslint Error: Unexpected 'this'. (unexpected_a);
            // What is the proper way to call another function inside the same
            // Object that will pass jslint?
            this.functionOne();
        }
    };

    myObject.functionTwo();
}());
```

Comment: There's no need to use the `this` directive. You're well familiar with Crockford's critique that using `this` makes JavaScript code like an Abbott and Costello skit! ;^D Refactor as in my answer and you can skip that shortcut -- and have more manageable code!

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: Refrain from using any but necessary jslint directives when fixing code to maximize the benefits of JSLint.

JSLint would prefer you arrange your code like this (no `this` required. Avoid `this` where possible):

```
/*jslint devel */
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var myObject;

    function functionOneDef() {
        console.log("functionOne called by functionTwo");
    }

    function functionTwoDef() {
        functionOneDef();
    }

    myObject = {
        functionOne: functionOneDef,    
        functionTwo: functionTwoDef
    };

    myObject.functionTwo();
}());
```