# JSLint Unexpected 'this' Error

Tags: javascript, jslint

Why am I getting the following JSLint error from the code below:

> JSLint : Unexpected 'this'.

```
var environment = {
    development: "Development",
    staging: "Staging",
    production: "Production",
    current: function () {
        return process.env.ASPNET_ENV || this.development;
    },
    isDevelopment: function () {
        return this.current() === this.development;
    },
    isStaging: function () {
        return this.current() === this.staging;
    },
    isProduction: function () {
        return this.current() === this.production;
    }
};
```

I have already seen a few similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422801/fix-for-jslint-unexpected-this-error) one but none deal with the code above, where 'this' is used in a different manner.

Comment: Maybe you could find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314944/jslint-error-unexpected-this

Comment: I suggest to use eslint instead, which is a lot more configurable: http://eslint.org/ . I guess Crockford doesn't want you to use `this` at all.

Comment: Yep, this is a dupe. Check [the question in mentioned by @RomanAlesenkov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314944/jslint-error-unexpected-this). This (no pun intended, ha ha) rule is new for the ES6 version of JSLint, and has an option to turn the rule off throughout your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very strange, but seems like JSLint doesn't allow 'this' by default.

However, there's a **'Tolerate this'** option available in their docs. So I'd suppose adding an option to your jslint config, like this:

```
/*jslint this:true */
```